# classicthesis StrSubstitute and accented character

Tags: classicthesis, microtype

I have a "second order" incompatibility problem between: classicthesis, StrSubstitute and accented characters. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
Il modello associa un valore di \StrSubstitute{verità}{x}{y}\
ad ogni formula.
\end{document}
```

The compilation gives the following error:

```
! Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }.
```

But if I remove the classicthesis package, or remove the StrSubstitute command or remove the accented character: then the compilation works without errors!

Comment: this isn't really related to `classicthesis` other than it loads `microtype`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xstring` functions use `\edef` which means that any commands that do not work by pure expansion are likely to fail.  You get the same error with this simplified input

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}
Il modello associa un valore di 
\edef\foo{verità}

ad ogni formula.
\end{document}
```

You could use

```
 {\def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}\StrSubstitute{verità}{x}{y}}
```

which makes no error, but drops the accent, depending on the actual requirement it is probably easiest to use an expandable string replace function rather than xstring.

this for example replaces x by y while preserving the accented a

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\repl{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { #2 } { #3 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Il modello associa un valore di \repl{vxerità}{x}{y}
ad ogni formula.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you suggest an expandable string replace function? I need to replace the "!" character used in the \index command with a space.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini updated answer

Comment: maybe `\usepackage{l3regex}` is required?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini oh only if you have an old installation, I tested the answer as posted, regex has been a part of core expl3 for some time

Comment: With egreg's edit the MWE now needs `xparse` and there seems to be a `\l_tmpa_tl` missing in `\regex_replace_once:nnN { #2 } { #3 }`.

Comment: @moewe I shall summon the culprit to come back and fix it!

Answer (score 5):

The problem, as you discovered, is that `\StrSubstitute` executes `\edef` on its arguments. However, this can be avoided.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

Il modello associa un valore di
\saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
\StrSubstitute{virità}{i}{e}
\restoreexpandmode\
ad ogni formula.

\bigskip

\saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
\StrSubstitute{viritò}{ò}{à}
\restoreexpandmode\

\end{document}
```

If you never need other modes (check the manual, section 3.1.1), you can issue `\noexpandarg` in the preamble and forget about saving and restoring it.

An easier method might be to use an `expl3` implementation (currently `classicthesis` raises an error, which you can safely ignore).

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xStrSubstitute}{mmmo}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 } { #3 }
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
   { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
   { \tl_set_eq:NN #4 \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Il modello associa un valore di
\xStrSubstitute{virità}{i}{e}\
ad ogni formula.

\bigskip

\xStrSubstitute{viritò}{ò}{à}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`listofitems` to the rescue.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\loiStrSubstitute[3]{%
  \setsepchar{#2}%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mylist{\ifnum\xcnt=1\else#3\fi\x}%
}
\begin{document}
Il modello associa un valore di \loiStrSubstitute{verità}{e}{x}\
ad ogni formula.

\loiStrSubstitute{verità}{à}{x}

\loiStrSubstitute{verititità}{i}{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a star version of the macro that only substitutes the first occurrence,

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\loiStrSubstitute{%
  \@ifstar{\loiStrSubstitutefirst}{\loiStrSubstituteall}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\loiStrSubstituteall[3]{%
  \setsepchar{#2}%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mylist{\ifnum\xcnt=1\else#3\fi\x}%
}
\newcommand\loiStrSubstitutefirst[3]{%
  \setsepchar{#2}%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mylist{\ifnum\xcnt=1\else\ifnum\xcnt=2\relax#3\else#2\fi\fi\x}%
}
\begin{document}
Il modello associa un valore di \loiStrSubstitute{verità}{e}{x}\
ad ogni formula.

\loiStrSubstitute{verità}{à}{x}

\loiStrSubstitute{verititità}{i}{o}

\loiStrSubstitute*{verititità}{i}{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]