# Using \vec inside \StrSubstitute to simplify math notation

Tags: xstring

I'm using several different calculi (programming languages) in a work, and I'm trying to define a tool to simplify my notation for them by replacing text with the proper notation; as of now, I've been playing with the following code (using tikz's `foreach`):

```tex
\newcommand{\format}[2]{%
\def\myformula{#1}%
\foreach \myfrom/\myto in {#2}%
{%
\StrSubstitute{\myformula}{\myfrom}{\myto}[\mytmp]%
\global\let\myformula\mytmp%
}%
\myformula%
}
```

There are a few commands which don't seem to play along with that. E.g., if I try to write:

```
$\format{k<xs>}{</\langle,>/\rangle,xs/\vec{x}}$
```

I get the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \xs_arg_iv.
```

Which seem to appear when simply trying to use `\vec` inside `\StrSubstitute`. The following results in the same issue:

```
$\StrSubstitute{k\langle xs\rangle}{xs}{\vec{x}}[\mytmp]$
```

What is going wrong here, and how could I fix it? Also, is there a simpler way to achieve what I'm trying (give a simplified, ASCII notation for a calculus)? I should note that a regex-like replace would be ideal, but I couldn't find out how to do that (unless of course I use LuaTeX).

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, I've tried making a minimal working example. Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\format}[2]{%
\def\myformula{#1}%
\foreach \myfrom/\myto in {#2}%
{%
\StrSubstitute{\myformula}{\myfrom}{\myto}[\mytmp]%
\global\let\myformula\mytmp%
}%
\myformula%
}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Test: $\format{k<xs>}{</\langle,>/\rangle,xs/\vec{x}}$

\end{document}
```

It seems that, without both `MnSymbol` and `accents`, everything works out as expected. By simply adding `MnSymbol` (but no `accents`), it won't even compile. By adding both (or just `accents`, without `MnSymbol`), the issue appears and it compiles, but with the error.

Comment: It's not clear how `\format{k<xs>}{</\langle,>/\rangle,xs/\vec{x}}` would be easier to input than `k\langle\vec{x}\rangle`

Comment: @egreg, right, on small examples like that one I could surely write the code directly. But on larger expressions it may become cumbersome.

Comment: By the way it's recommended to include a minimal working example

Comment: Try adding `\protect` before `\vec`. In any case in my version it works perfectly without modification

Comment: In any case there's l3regex (read interface3.pdf) for some "simple" regex, but you need lots of intricate knowledge on how tokens work in LaTeX to use it

Comment: Related questions regarding expansion issue with strsubstitute [microtype - classicthesis StrSubstitute and accented character - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433777/classicthesis-strsubstitute-and-accented-character)

Comment: @egreg Well it's okay to suggest people of "better" ways to do things, but in this case clearly OP already know the "do nothing" way and (generally speaking) people have different ideas of what make the source code good (\over in plain TeX is a well-known example, for one...)

Comment: @user202729, you're right: I should have provided a minimal working example. When tried to doing so I noticed what you mention, it worked. The issue seems to be appearing by the use of another package I was using; I'll edit the answer to include the example and better explain this.